# Jquery Data table Export is not working after search or filter in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

Im using jquery data table in asp.net MVC 4 to bind the Data.

Issue is,

> After search or filter, The new set of data is not exporting into
>   Excel. It always exports data when was page loaded.

The above issues i'm facing only in IE but in chrome working as expected.

Code:

```
var table = $('#gamtbl').DataTable(
    {
        sScrollY: 450,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        fixedColumns: {
            leftColumns: 2
        },
        "sDom": '<"H"Tlfr>tip<"F">',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "../../Images/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [{
                "sExtends": "collection",
                "sButtonText": "Export",
                "aButtons": [{
                    'sExtends': "csv",
                    "mColumns": [0,1, 2, 3, 4]
                },
                    {
                        'sExtends': "xls",
                        "sFileName": "*.xls",
                        "mColumns": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
                    },
                ],
            }],
        }
    });
    table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
        $('input', 'th:nth-child(' + (colIdx + 1) + ')').on('keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column(colIdx)
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [**`oSelectorOpts`**](http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/button_options#oSelectorOpts) (old "legacy" documentation). You need to specify that you only want to export filtered rows :

```js
"aButtons": [
  {
    sExtends: "csv",
    mColumns: [0,1, 2, 3, 4],
    oSelectorOpts: { filter: "applied", order: "current" }
  },
  ....
]
```

But you should really consider using the [**`Buttons`**](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) plugin instead of the retired TableTools, now you are using dataTables 1.10.x anyway ...

Comment: Thanks David, oSelectorOpts: { filter: "applied", order: "current" } is not working, I have changed aButtons to Buttons and its working as expected